Paris & minimum baking rights
Now that Adaptive Issuance is live, can someone answer to me whether the following are correct:
John is a baker who staked 1200 tez and receives 9600 tez delegated.  John gets baking rights.
Jack is a baker who staked 2000 and receives 4000 staked. Jack also gets baking rights.

They are indeed correct

Yes, both are correct. John and Jack get baking rights.
Here the rules:

The minimum baking power a delegate/baker needs is 6,000 tez, as defined by the protocol constant 'minimum_stake'.
Delegated tez only contribute half of their value to the baking power.
External stakes are limited by the delegate's parameter 'limit-of-staking-over-baking'. Any amount above this limit is treated as delegated tez. (Note: the delegate's limit is capped by the protocol constant 'global_limit_of_staking_over_baking', which is 5.)
Tez in delegation are limited by the protocol constant 'limit_of_delegation_over_baking', which is 9.

Another illustrative example:
Norbert, who is also a baker, staked 600 tez and received 10,800 tez in delegations. However, Norbert does not get any baking power or rights due to the delegation limit over baking, which is 9. Therefore, the delegated tez are capped at 5,400 (9 x 600), and Norbert's baking power is only about 3,300 (600 + 5,400/2), which is below the current minimum requirement of 6,000 tez.
Note: The values/constants taken in the example are from ParisC protocol.

As ghast rightly said, both receives baking rights.
In John's case, his 1200 staked tez counts twice (2400), plus the 9600 delegated tez, giving him a total baking power equivalent to 12000 tez. For Jack, both his 2000 staked tez and the 4000 tez staked to him count twice, also resulting in a baking power equivalent to 12000 tez. So despite having different compositions of staked and delegated funds, John and Jack end up with equal baking power in this scenario.
